# Android anchor tags not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, android, android-browser

*Edit:* Tested on **Droid X** running **Android version 2.2.1**

I'm developing a webpage designed to run on mobile devices, specifically Android and iOS. Everything seems to be working on iOS, but I'm experiencing weird behavior on Android. Anchor tags seem to not function.

Specifically, the last anchor within a div seems to have trouble. There's nothing special about these anchors:

```
<div class="footer">
    <a class="baselink" href="http://www.google.com">
        Having issues? Try the basic version</a>
</div>
```

Nothing happens when the link is tapped. I am able to open the link after a long-press, but that isn't an acceptable solution. The link should open when tapped. Every other anchor on the page functions as expected.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to share a link as external requests are blocked by our firewall.

Comment: Good question, but I need a little more information. Are you testing throug an Android emulator or a real device? Which Android version do you test on?

Comment: I'm testing on a real Droid X with Android version 2.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

something to refer to; it may help: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?112752-Anchor-lt-a-gt-tags-not-working-on-Android-%280.97%29

Comment: The post claims this was corrected as of Android 0.98. I'm testing on a Droid X running Android version 2.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have some funny things going on in your source code or/and css. I've tried this code (see below) on my own website without trouble using HTC Desire HD (Android 2.2.1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Test link</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" > 
</head> 
<body> 
<div class="footer"> 
    <a class="baselink" href="http://www.google.com"> 
        Having issues? Try the basic version</a> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

This is the actual link: [test link](http://skogberg.eu/test.html)